# How To Know If List is Full

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine

I've created a `List` with fixed size

```
private List<ushort> responseData = new List<ushort>(7);
```

Items are added on a reactive observable but I would like to know if it's full on each subscribe.

Currently It is checked by

```
if (responseData.Count == 7)
```

Since responseData size will be dynamic, I won't be using the static `7` in both initialisation of `List` and checking if it's full. However, I was just wondering if I set responseData size already; Can't it check without using the size reference again?

I highly value any response.

Comment: Are you looking for `responseData.Count == responseData.Capacity`?

Comment: Well, 7 is just the initial size. Past that, the underlying data structure will be expanded to handle new items. It seems that you want to have a List with a maximum size. If so, you need to give more info on how you plan to use it.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes, but is is there different way to check? I'll rephrase my question.

Comment: You could implement an extension method called IsFull() to List<ushort> and this extension method would be accessible by any instance of List<ushort>...
This doc may be of help: https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/how-to-implement-and-call-a-custom-extension-method

Comment: Now I'm not sure what exactly you are looking for. You can always write an extension method called `IsFull` that ultimately checks `responseData.Count == responseData.Capacity`. Can you define, precisely, what you mean by "is full", and what you mean by "more reliable or smarter approach" (i.e. how is the current approach not reliable, not smart)?

Comment: A list can't ever be full.  It can store an infinite number of items.  If you want to use a data structure with a fixed capacity that will actually fill up, you'll need to use a different data structure (possibly one backed by a List, but that actually prevents itself in some way from exceeding the capacity) and could have members to indicate if it's full, or any other operations that would make sense for a collection with a capacity.

Comment: @Sweeper turns out you wrote exactly what I was looking for from the beginning, but I thought `Capacity` was another custom variable since I didn't know it back when you commented. Anyway, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you might be thinking of the `List<T>.Capacity` property?

When you initialise a List, you can specify the internal capacity which indicates the number of items that can be added to a List before a resize needs to take place. The default is 4 for the list capacity [*used to be, needs confirmation it still is*].

So, if you create a new list as such:

```
var myList = new List<int>(100);
```

You could create an extension method that adds and checks for you:

```
public static class ListExtension
{
    public static bool Add<T> ( this List<T> list, T item, out bool isFull )
    {
        isFull = false;
        if ( list.Count == list.Capacity )
        {
            isFull = true;
            return false;
        }

        list.Add ( item );
        isFull = list.Count == list.Capacity;
        return true;
    }
}
```

Now, this is stated in the Microsoft [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.capacity):

> Capacity is always greater than or equal to Count. If Count exceeds
> Capacity while adding elements, the capacity is increased by
> automatically reallocating the internal array before copying the old
> elements and adding the new elements.

Therefore, the extension method should only ever allow you to add items up to the initial `Capacity`, and no more. When used like this, `var success = myList.Add(item, out var isFull)`, `isFull` will indicate whether the list is full. The return value will indicate whether the operation was successful.

Comment: I see, I guess my question was impossible, I learned that we will have to use `==` operand inevitably. But checking against this property answers my question since we don't have to use `7` or a variable again. Plus it is safer.